# How to access the collection embedded in query result which is returned with Entity SQL in EF4.3

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

Actually I learnt this query method from book , chapter 5.

```
SELECT c.LastName,
(SELECT VALUE MAX(a.PostalCode) FROM c.Addresses as a)
FROM PEF.Contacts AS c
```

And my question is, how shall I access the values in the second column, which is a collection of int values. I trace its type by running:

```
string query = "SELECT c.LastName, (SELECT VALUE MAX(a.PostalCode) FROM c.Addresses as a) " +
                "FROM PEF.Contacts AS c ";
ObjectQuery<DbDataRecord> records = this.objEntity.CreateQuery<DbDataRecord>(query);
foreach (DbDataRecord record in records)
{
    Trace.WriteLine("Type: " + record[1]);
}
```

And it is: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int16]

However, I cannot cast the column to List, nor does iterating through record[1] directly with foreach work.

Since the official forum of this book is not active any more, hope someone could help here.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: `(record[1] as List<short?>)` returns your list, but this list contains nullable short values, so if you want get just int values, so you can do next: `(record[1] as List<short?>).Where(o=>o.HasValue).Select(o=>((int)o)).ToList()`

Comment: @Jonik, thank you so much, it works! I missed it is nullable.